# Update field in a document based on the condition in Kibana/Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to update particular field in document based on some condition. In general sql way, I want to do following.

```
Update index indexname
set name =  "XXXXXX"
where source: file and name :  "YYYYYY"
```

I am using below to update all the documents but I am not able to add any condition.

```
POST indexname/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "name": "XXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the template, I am using:

```
{
  "indexname": {
    "mappings": {
      "idxname123": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "date1": {
            "type": "date",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone guide me how to add condition to it as mentioned above for the source and name.

Thanks,
Babu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the below query to what you are looking for. I'm assuming `name` and `source` are your fields in your index.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.name = 'XXXXX'",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": {
              "value": "YYYYY"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "source": {
              "value": "file"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can probably make use of any of the [Full Text Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) or [Term Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html) inside the [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for either searching/updating/deletions.

Do spend sometime in going through them.

**Note:** Make use of `Term Queries` only if your field's datatype is `keyword`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and really appreciate your help. I am trying based on your suggestion and getting following error: {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [id] fields, but found none"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [id] fields, but found none"
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: @Babu, can you retry the above query. I've changed `"source"` to `"inline"` in the above query and it should now work.

Comment: Thank you for quick response and now query is working fine but I don't see "Name" field is updating. Here is the response I am getting. Do you see any mistake how I am doing -                                                            {
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 0,
  "updated": 0,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 0,
  "version_conflicts": 0,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": []
}

Comment: @Babu, could you update the question by adding your mapping detail? `GET <your_index_name>/_mapping`

Comment: Your POST would be something like this `POST indexname/_update_by_query` and not `POST <indexname>/_update_by_query`. Remove the `<` and `>` and try. If this is not the case, just remove the `script` part of query, replace `_update_by_query` with `_search` and execute the query. Let me know if you see any result. Try these and let me know.

Comment: One more thing you can do is execute the `Term Query` on `keyword` datatype. i.e. replace `name` with `name.keyword` and `source` with `source.keyword` and try the query.

Comment: Yes, after replacing source.keyword and name.keyword its updated. Thank you very much for your help and really appreciate for your time.